# Why does qTip2 use .removeData() and .data() in the growl example

Tags: qtip2, jgrowl

I'm starting to use qTip2, and I'm looking the demos of the site. I was trying to understand this [one](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#growl) but I didn't understand this so much. I can't understand this part:

```
...
}).removeData('qtip');
...
$(this).data('qtip');
...
```

I'd like to know why and for what `.removeData()` and `.data()` were used.
Could someone help me to understand it?

Comment: There is no need for signatures in posts. Please don't add them back when they get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official forum of qtip 2, the creator of qtip2, Craig, answered me!

Craig Wrote: "The `removeData` is just a "hack" to allow more than one qTip to be bound to a single element at any one time, hence allowing multiple jGrowl(s). The `.data()` call is just there to grab the qTip API object from each of the matched objects."

:)